# R: llply fully reproducible results in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

what changes should i do to have a reproducible result here? I run it multiple times and the result vector is different. Thanks for any help.

```
cl <- makeCluster(2)

registerDoParallel(2)

set.seed(123)

results <- unlist(llply(seq_along(1:4), .fun = function(x){
  runif(1)} ,.parallel = T, 
  .paropts = list(.export=ls(.GlobalEnv))))


stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example will give reproducible results on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows:

```
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
opts <- list(preschedule=TRUE)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, 123)
r <- llply(1:20,
           .fun = function(x) runif(10),
           .parallel = TRUE,
           .paropts = list(.options.snow=opts))
```

The `preschedule=TRUE` option is needed to prevent doParallel from using load balancing which would make the mapping of tasks to workers unpredictable.

If you're using Linux or Mac OS X and you want doParallel to use `mclapply`, you could use this approach:

```
if (.Platform$OS.type != "windows") {
  registerDoParallel(2)
  RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
  set.seed(123)
  mc.reset.stream()
  r <- llply(1:20,
             .fun = function(x) runif(10),
             .parallel = TRUE)
}
```

This works because `mclapply` uses prescheduling by default. It won't work on Windows because doParallel will implicitly create a cluster object, and the RNG initialization won't have any effect.

Note that in your example, you're creating a cluster object but not registering it, so it isn't going to be used by doParallel. You've got to use `registerDoParallel(cl)`, otherwise doParallel will either use `mclapply` on a Posix computer or an implicitly created cluster object on a Windows computer. Obviously it's very important to initialize the cluster workers that will actually perform the parallel computations.

Comment: thanks for the detail answer Amazing! Yes i am trying to code something that works in any OS. So your first solution is the one i am using. Thanks!. Let me ask you follow up questions: What is the difference between .options.multicore and .options.snow ? Why did you use a vector c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) as set.seed instead of an interger. If instead of having runif(10) you have a custom function that has a "set.seed(1234)" inside. That set.seed should be remove to avoid the a new multithread conflict that would not allow reproducibility?

Comment: @donpresente .options.multicore is only used by the "mclapply" backend, while .options.snow is only used by the "cluster" backend. It allows you to pass backend specific options without losing portability.

Comment: @donpresente I should have passed 123 to clusterSetRNGStream. I got mixed up with some of the internal functions that use the 7-integer seed used by the L'Ecuyer-CMRG generator. I fixed this mistake in my answer.

Comment: amazing! thanks again! A whole class on parallelization in 3 posts :)